# How IEDriver bit is determined for the execution

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-iedriver

We have 2 machines in which we run IE selenium Test scripts. In both the machine IE 32 bit is configured. In one machine it types faster and in another machine it types each word. So in that machine i changed the IEDriver bit version as 64 and it worked as expected.

My question is, how the IE driver bit is determined as 64 or 32. Is there any relation between OS bit version ?? like if OS is 64 IE should also be 64 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are technical reasons why the “bitness” of the driver must match that of the browser, mostly stemming from the fact that the driver uses Windows hook procedures for processing keystrokes by default. Those technical reasons are outlined in [a blog post](https://jimevansmusic.blogspot.com/2014/09/screenshots-sendkeys-and-sixty-four.html) written by the driver author (me) some years ago. The tricky bit is knowing whether the browser is actually 32-bit or 64-bit.

You see, IE uses multiple processes when browsing, notably a broker process (which handles the outer frame of the browser), and content processes (usually one per tab, which actually renders the content). Starting with IE10, though, the challenge is that those processes (the broker and the content processes) can have ***different*** bitnesses. In fact, on 64-bit Windows, this is the default, where the broker process is 64-bit, and the content processes are 32-bit. Element interactions like sending keystrokes happen in the content process, so that’s what the driver must match.

That means the most common case is that one should use the 32-bit IE driver, even on 64-bit Windows. It must be pointed out that there are some cases where one can get a 64-bit content process (usually based on Enhanced Protected Mode), but these are a vast minority of cases.

Answer (score 0):

If you use IEDriverServer.exe 32-bit execution will be faster and if you use 64-bit execution will be slower irrespective of your OS. So, use 32-bit as its faster. I have tried with both 32 and 64-bit, trust me 64-bit is way too slow.

Answer (score 0):

From https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#internet-explorer-driver:

> The driver supports running 32-bit and 64-bit versions of the browser.
>   The choice of how to determine which "bit-ness" to use in launching
>   the browser depends on which version of the IEDriverServer.exe is
>   launched. If the 32-bit version of IEDriverServer.exe is launched, the
>   32-bit version of IE will be launched. Similarly, if the 64-bit
>   version of IEDriverServer.exe is launched, the 64-bit version of IE
>   will be launched.

AFAIK, you can run either the 32 or 64-bit driver on 64-bit Windows; I'd expect that you can only run the 32-bit driver on 32-bit Windows.

Anecdotally, the 32-bit driver is considered "faster" than its 64-bit counterpart.  But--given that perceived speed is influenced by the system-under-tests's CPU/RAM--that would need to be benchmarked to be certain.  That being said, I have previously used the 32-bit version on 64-bit systems because it did appear faster (especially WRT to text entry).